# Reference existing resources in cloud formation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudformation

Is there a way to reference an existing resource in cloudformation. I am looking for something similar to terraform’s datasource facility where I can find a resource by tag, etc. and then use a property such as Id.

I have an existing security group with a consistent name across accounts. If I could look up this SG in the template I could use the ID.

Azure does this. terraform does this.

Comment: There's this but I'm not sure its quite what you're after. CloudFormation is good, but also somewhat basic https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-import-existing-resources-into-a-cloudformation-stack/